# How do I change my name on Steam?

Tags: steam

I have a name on Steam, but when I play multiplayer Team Fortress, it shows my email address.

I have already set my name in Steam, but I want the game to show my name.

Answer (score 30):

Open [your profile](https://steamcommunity.com/my/),

[image: Profile page]

click [edit profile](https://steamcommunity.com/my/edit/),

[image: Edit Profile Button]

change your name

[image: Profile Name Box]

and save the changes.

[image: Save Changes Button]

Note: Everything might not look the same, as I use some addins (steamdb is displayed in first picture, lastpass in third) and your language might be different.

Comment: @aytimothy All your page are belong to us.

Comment: Out of curiosity what's the [TR] stand for? (I always find clan tags like that interesting)

Comment: @Robotnik Short for "turkey", not a clan.

Answer (score 15):

[image]

Go to the Friends List, hit the arrow near your name, click "Change Profile Name", choose your Name, and you are done!

Thank you to ardaozkal for the image, Props to you!

Comment: +1 this is the usual way, it's much faster as well.

Comment: Hey, I'd edit your answer with more info but it looks like you will edit it, ping me if you want me to edit it. [Also here is a picture if you want to include it.](http://ardao.me/files/e2lv.png).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to change your username in the client (Note: You can still use my other answer in client), you can check @Magmagod's answer, or do this. This also works in games too, so you can change your name during a match etc.

Open up Steam Settings, then switch to the friends tab (if you are in-game, it'll automatically start from Friends tab):

[image: Friends tab]

Change your name, and hit the "OK" button.

[image: OK button]

Note: I'm using a theme, this might not look the same on your end.

Comment: Why did you create two separate answers when merging them both would have been a wiser choice? It's not even a fundamentally different way, it's just an alternative

Comment: @skully I asked in chat and we thought that putting multiple answers would be better, considering they are different.